# Checking file permissions in linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, chmod

I need to change the permissions of files within a directory, such as :

- if the group has no permissions, others should have no permissions either
- if the group has permissions, nothing should change

But in a single command.

I'm pretty sure I have to use `chmod` for the change itself.
My biggest problem is actually how to know if the group has permissions or not? thereafter, use this information in a single command

Comment: You can use `find` to find all the files where group permissions are empty, then use `chmod o=` to empty the other permissions.

Comment: [How do I find files with no group permissions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179030/how-do-i-find-files-with-no-group-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$(stat -c "%a" "$1" | cut -b 2)" -eq 0 ] && chmod o-rwx "$1"
```

explanation:

```
stat -c "%a" "$1"   # get file permission as octal number
cut -b 2            # extract second number (-> group)
-eq 0               # test if group permissin is 0
&&                  # then...
chmod o-rwx "$1"    # remove other permissions
```